# Can´t query AVAssetTrack´s MediaType

Tags: xcode, avfoundation, avasset

i´m trying to get the mediaType from an AVAssetTrack but i never get one of these logs.

```
AVAssetTrack *track1 = cell.videoPlayer.currentItem.asset.tracks.firstObject;

                    if (track1.mediaType == AVMediaTypeAudio) {

                        NSLog(@"AVMediaTypeAudio");

                    }

                    if (track1.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo) {

                        NSLog(@"AVMediaTypeVideo");

                    }
```

but here´s a log of the tracks(array). this shows me the information i would need, but i can´t query it.

```
NSLog(@"%lu: %@", indexPath.row ,cell.videoPlayer.currentItem.asset.tracks);

"<AVAssetTrack: 0x1c0018ff0, trackID = 1, mediaType = soun>",
"<AVAssetTrack: 0x1c0018d90, trackID = 2, mediaType = vide>"
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [isEqual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418795-isequal) method.

```
AVAssetTrack *track1 = cell.videoPlayer.currentItem.asset.tracks.firstObject;

if ([track1.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {

    NSLog(@"AVMediaTypeAudio");

}

if ([track1.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

    NSLog(@"AVMediaTypeVideo");

}
```